# mongodb how to use aggregate like populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

The code example is in ***Mongo Playground***

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/W4Qt4oX0ZRP

Assume the following documents

```js
[
  {
    _id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e8",
    user: {
      name: "Tom",
      sex: 1,
      age: 23
    },
    dream: [
      {
        label: "engineer",
        industry: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222909",
        type: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222951",

      },
      {
        label: "programmer",
        industry: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222909",
        type: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222951",

      }
    ],
    works: [
      {
        name: "any engineer",
        company: "5dd7fd51b0ae1837a08d00c8",
        skill: [
          "5dc3998e2cf66bad16efd61b",
          "5dc3998e2cf66bad16efd61e"
        ],

      },
      {
        name: "any programmer",
        company: "5dd7fd9db0ae1837a08d00e2",
        skill: [
          "5dd509e05de2b22f8e67e1b7",
          "5dd509e05de2b22f8e67e1bb"
        ],

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to use `aggregate` `$lookup` `$unwind`

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$dream",

    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "industry",
      localField: "dream.industry",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dream.industry"
    },

  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$dream.industry",

    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "type",
      localField: "dream.type",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "dream.type"
    },

  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$dream.type",

    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$works",

    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "company",
      localField: "works.company",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "works.company"
    },

  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$works.company",

    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "skill",
      localField: "works.skill",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "works.skill"
    },

  },

])
```

Executing the above code did not get the desired result!

### This is what i expect

```js
{
  _id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e8",
  user: {
    name: 'Tom',
    sex: 1,
    age: 23
  },
  dream: [
    {
      label: 'engineer',
      industry: {
        _id: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222909",           // Industry doc _id
        name: 'IT',
        createdAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z"
      },
      type: {
        _id: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222951",           // Type doc _id
        name: 'job',
        createdAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z"
      },
    },
    {
      label: 'programmer',
      industry: {
        _id: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222909",           // Industry doc _id
        name: 'IT',
        createdAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z"
      },
      type: {
        _id: "5e06b16fb0670d7538222951",           // Type doc _id
        name: 'job',
        createdAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-12-28T01:35:44.070Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  works: [
    {
      name: 'any engineer',
      company: {
        _id: "5dd7fd51b0ae1837a08d00c8",          // Company doc _id
        name: 'alibaba',
        area: 'CN',
      },
      skill: [
        { 
          _id: "5dc3998e2cf66bad16efd61b",        // Skill doc _id
          name: 'Java' 
        }, 
        { 
          _id: "5dc3998e2cf66bad16efd61e",        // Skill doc _id
          name: 'Php' 
        }, 
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'any programmer',
      company: {
        _id: "5dd7fd9db0ae1837a08d00e2",           // Company doc _id
        name: 'microsoft',
        area: 'EN',
      },
      skill: [
        { 
          _id: "5dd509e05de2b22f8e67e1b7",           // Skill doc _id
          name: 'Golang' 
        },
        { 
          _id: "5dd509e05de2b22f8e67e1bb",         // Skill doc _id
          name: 'Node.js'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

The expected result is `dream` is an array, `works` is an array, and `dream.industry` changed from ObjectId to document, `dream.type` changed from ObjectId to document, `works.company` changed from ObjectId to document

When I use populate, I can do it easily

```js
Model.find()
 .populate('dream.industry')
 .populate('dream.type')
 .populate('works.company')
 .populate('works.skill')
 .lean()
```

I refer to the following questions

> 1. [mongoose aggregate lookup array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249218/mongoose-aggregate-lookup-array) (Almost the same as my question, But not resolved)
> 2. [$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array)

hope to get everyone's help, thank you!

Comment: You need to give real ObjectId values in the sample document  to be easier for us. Even better it would be nice to create a sample in https://mongoplayground.net

Comment: what is the result of your current code? 

Notice that MongoDB object ids must save as ObjectId, 
for example: 
        industry: ObjectId("5e06b16fb0670d7538222909"),
if you save mongo ids as string, the lookup stage will not work.

Comment: @Amin Shojaei, Thank you! The result of the current code is in 
 https://mongoplayground.net/p/W4Qt4oX0ZRP

Comment: Honestly, i tried to understand how the current result and your expected result are different, but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The expected result is ```dream``` is an array, ```works``` is an array, and ```dream.industry``` changed from ObjectId to document, ```dream.type``` changed from ObjectId to document, ```works.company``` changed from ObjectId to document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it easier i would not change the current pipeline but just add a `$group` stage to end of it in order to re-structure the data.

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        user: {$first: "$user"},
        dream: {$addToSet: "$dream"},
        works: {$addToSet: "$works"}
    }
}
```

With that said if you are using Mongo version 3.6+ i do recommend you use the "newer" version of [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to re-write your pipeline to be a bit more efficient by avoiding all these `$unwind`'s.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @tom slabbaert, Yes, it's version 3.6+, how to use the "newer" version of ```$lookup``` to re-write my pipeline ?